# highcharts boxplot data labels

Tags: highcharts, label, boxplot

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr34L.png)
Hi, I´ve come accross this picture. I am using highcharts.com and already have a  boxplot rendered, and I would like to add 3 additional lines with some text for each individual boxplot. Later I wanna render gridlines so it will look like a table, I have drawn my idea very quickly in paint, how it should look in the end. Any ideas how to achieve that with highcharts? Thanks
[Picture with gridlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0hRn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheive the wanted result, you can use `grouped-categories` module: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [{
        name: "Fruit",
        categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    }, {
        name: "Vegetable",
        categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
    }, {
        name: "Fish",
        categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
    }]
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aest25yg/

Comment: cheers, that plugin looks useful... I am trying to add a label, like y-axis label to those grouped categories, any ideas how to achieve that? My idea which I want to achieve would be like this:
![Grouped Categories with labels](http://i67.tinypic.com/sfypn8.png)

Comment: To add additional labels, you can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ny7Ljo93/